# ReactJS how to allow changes on an uncontrolled input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a have a Component that generates text inputs with these conditions:

- I want to initialize it with a value
- Should be uncontrolled

### EDIT

I tried `defaultValue` but it affects the next Components created wherein the value stays the same for succeeding Components. As you can see below (image) the 3rd to the end of the row are all `August 8, 2016` and so on when the correct values should be the same at the 2nd (image). I encounter this when setting the value via `defaultValue` or via `componentDidMount` as posted in the answers.

[image: via defaultValue or componentDidMount]

I also tried `value` but it gives me an error saying I should include an `onChange`

So here is currently the display of my table component using the code below.

[image: via value]

Each row is represented by the Component below:

```
var ScheduleResultRow = React.createClass({
render: function() {
    return(
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" value={this.props.slot.date} /></td>
                <td><input type="text" value={this.props.slot.day} /></td>
                <td><input type="text" value={this.props.slot.time} /></td>
                <td><input type="text" value={this.props.players.player1 + " - " + this.props.players.player2} /></td>
                <td><input type="text" value={this.props.slot.field} /></td>
            </tr>
        )
}
});
```

As you can see the value is generated by it's parent Component transferred through `props`. I don't want to keep a state of the rows because it's just for display purposes and it's just a calculated from the state of its parent.

Any idea how do I achieve this? Any help would be very much appreciated.

### UPDATE

I made it work by adding `onChange` event with the following function below:

```
handleChange: function(e) {
    this.refs[e.target.value].value = e.target.value;
}
```

The only problem with this is that it throws console error:

```
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined`
```

That error probably helped make it work. lol

Comment: `I tried defaultValue but it affects the next Components created wherein the value stays the same for succeeding inputs.` Can you elaborate on that? Isn't this working for you? https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/

Comment: @Héctor Thank you for your question. Yes I've just updated my question, I've added another image the 1st one. Hope that clarifies it.

Comment: Ok, so If I'm following you correctly, what you want to achieve is a list of rows, where the n-1 rows are previously saved inputs, and the last one is the 'input row' and should come with default values for the user to add a new row. Am I right? In any case, I think it would be useful to see the parent component that renders all the `ScheduleResultRow`, can you share its code?

Comment: I don't think your onChange handler is actually doing anything... probably would still work with `handleChange: function(e) { return null; }`

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I'll try that as well, it's a bit hacky at the moment. But I will definitely come back here if I get any answer. Again, thank you @Héctor

Answer (score 3):

Use componentDidMount method: Initialize textboxes when they are added to DOM:

```
var ScheduleResultRow = React.createClass({
componentDidMount: function (){
   this.refs.date.value = this.props.slot.date;
   this.refs.day.value = this.props.slot.day;
   this.refs.time.value = this.props.slot.time;
   this.refs.player2.value = this.props.players.player1 + " - "     + this.props.players.player2;
   this.refs.field.value = this.props.slot.field;
},
render: function() {
    return(
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" ref="date"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" ref="day"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" ref="time"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" ref="player2"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" ref="field"/></td>
        </tr>
    )
  }
});
```

Comment: Works like a charm! thank you very much! Didn't think of `componentDidMount` :(

Comment: Just need to change a few to make it work. Missing comma before `render` and `this.refs.player2.value` should be `this.refs.players.value`.

Comment: Yup, I've added comma there... :)

Comment: I removed this as the answer because I encountered a problem. Wherein the succeeding values are repeated all over the next Component renders. :( But I upvoted it though. I've also edited my question for clarification.

Comment: This solution just ensures that whatever value is passed via properties gets rendered in values at time of loading/mounting component... You have to look at the way you're passing props to components (This is the only thing that will affect values inside your textboxes)